# how much time unpublished app remains into chrome web store?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I have published my app into chrome web store first time.I did some changes and was going to press publish link again but by mistake i clicked on unpublish link.

Now it is showing status as pending review. My question is i need create new app listing again ?  or i can publish previous app after review and how much time will it take ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publishing an extension in the CWS. This question fits better at https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/chromium-apps.

Comment: I do not have an unpublish link but I wish I would have. Can you tell where you found your unpublish link?

Comment: It is present in chrome developer dashboard.After publishing app there 3 links come on right hand side of published app. one is stats,another is unpublish and last one is edit.